# Sending JSON object data to HTML side?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a made a JSON object using Node JS functions, and now I want to send this JSON object to the HTMl side so that I can make a table with the data. However, it's not being sent over, and since I am quite new to Node JS, I'm unsure how I can send this JSON object over.

When I use Express to send the object and use fetch in the script of my HTML file, the console.log in Chrome developer tools (under the network tab) shows as pending, and data from the console.log does not show. I checked on Postman as well, and  the request to the localhost URL just shows it grinding as "Sending Request".

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const url = require("url");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);


app.use(express.json());
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const { query, pathname } = url.parse(req.url, true);
  if (pathname == "/") {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-type": "text/html" });
    const outMap = Array.from(teams)
      .map((el) => homepageTeamLister(teamsListHTML, el))
      .join("");

    res.end(outMap);
  } else if (pathname == "/player") {
    //res.writeHead(200, { "Content-type": "text/html" });

    app.get("/test", function (req, res) {
      res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "http://localhost:9000/test"
      );
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
      const myObj = { name: "John", age: 30 };
      res.send(myObj);
    });
  }
});

server.listen(9000, "127.0.0.1", () => {
  console.log("listening on port 9000");
});
```

And my HTML Script code:

```
console.log("Entered Script");
  fetch('/test')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log("Hi? : " , data); // { name: "John", age: 30 }
    })
    .catch(console.error);

    $.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:9000/test',
  complete: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
```

I have tried both the fetch function, and used AJAX, but both attempts did not work.

Comment: This is not how you create a server in express. You've mixed to different syntaxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your code for Express.js and HTML was not set up correctly.

You can preview the final code [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vigilant-mendeleev-xise6v)

place the HTML code below to `public/index.html`

```
<html>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js'></script>
<script>
  console.log("Entered Script");
  fetch("/test")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
     console.log("Hi? : ", data); // { name: "John", age: 30 }
    })
    .catch(console.error);

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://xise6v-9000.csb.app/test",
    complete: function(data) {
     console.log(data?.responseText);
    }
  });
</script>
</html>
```

update your app.js file to resemble the code below. I have included comments to provide more context and understanding:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);

// serve the html file under the public folder
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());


// correct way to declare the API
app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "http://localhost:9000/test"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
  const myObj = {name: "John", age: 30};
  res.send(myObj);
});

// use app listen instead
app.listen(9000, "127.0.0.1", () => {
  console.log("listening on port 9000");
});
```

You can preview the result by following this [link](https://xise6v-9000.csb.app/).

Answer (score -1):

try this pls:

```js
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const url = require("url");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

app.use(express.json());
app.get("/test", function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "http://localhost:9000/test"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
  const myObj = { name: "John", age: 30 };
  res.send(myObj);
});


app.listen(9000, "127.0.0.1", () => {
  console.log("listening on port 9000");
});
```

Comment: express.js is already a http server, so you do not need to write "http.createServer", and if you need to listen other request, you can use ""app.get("/", function (req, res)=>{})...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).